# Textbox and selectbox

Tags: html, textbox, drop-down-menu

I have an input field where user enters some data, which will then be stored in database. Later calculations will be done using that data. So user can enter any number in the field and other options i have to provide is 'last', 'new' , 'old'. He can either enter a number or select one option among the previous.

It'll be like

```
<input type="text"> and <select> working together
```

Is there any way i can do this? Please suggest me something

I'm open for anything, JS or JQUERY. Please help

Comment: You mean something like a ***combobox***?

Comment: In ComboBox you can only select from pre-defined values right?

Comment: possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180890/drop-down-with-free-input. In there is a description of how to change the ```combo.js``` source file from jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery [combify](https://github.com/tmooney3979/jquery.ui.combify) UI plugin of tmooney3979. I think it does what you ask for.

Comment: you can upvote if think the answer is really helpful in your context :)